# On Click event when tag clicked on not firing. How to capture event

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-it

I am using the following plugin for creating tags.  Tags are being created fine, Its just when I click on a tag, the tag click event does not fire. Please help.

aehlke.github.io/tag-it/‎

```
$('#myTags').tagit({
    select: true,
    sortable: true,
    triggerKeys: ['enter', 'comma', 'tab'],
    onTagClicked: function (evt, ui) {
        addEvent('onTagClicked: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
    }
});

<ul id="myTags"></ul>
<div id="events_container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `addEvent` function which is a custom function used in the demo [here](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html#eventTags).

```
var addEvent = function(text) {
  $('#events_container').append(text + '<br>');
};
```

You basically don't need this function it was just used by the demo to show the event clicked. And probably you forgot to copy paste that function ;)

Try to alert in the `onTagClicked`

```
$('#myTags').tagit({
    select: true,
    sortable: true,
    triggerKeys: ['enter', 'comma', 'tab'],
    onTagClicked: function (evt, ui) {
        alert("You clicked me");
        //do whatever you want to do here
    }
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pQT93/)**

Comment: I know, I was just checking if the demo would work too. I tried exactly as you mentioned and still it would not click. When I hover on a tag I see a cursor instead of the hand symbol, and it would not click. Although I can click on the x to delete the tag. Not sure as to what exactly is blocking it for the click event

Comment: My bad, I was utilizing the older version of the plugin. what a fool I am. Thanks yar. bohat bohat shukaria